# Include html from another file in the SP-masterpage

Tags: 2010, master-page, design

Our SP-site is used as a part of another non-SP site. The layout should look the same on both the SP-site and the non-SP site.

In the past, we have copy/pasted the html from the header and footer of the external site into the SharePoint master page. A preferred solution would be to include static html pages that SP can render as header and footer. That way, header and footer only need to be updated in one place. Is this possible?

Comment: How is the header/footer managed in the other site? is there an API you can pull the information with?

Comment: I'm working together with the people that are making the other site, so I have the option to request 'things'. For now, the header and footer are stored in static html pages. They use EpiServer 6, I'm not familiar with how it's done there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the header and footer HTML to separate .NET User Control and then just embed them in the master page.  Simple, straightforward, and clean.

Here's a fairly recent post on this topic:

http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/10/smart-headers-and-footers-using-asp-net-user-controls/

Happy to answer any follow-up questions you have.

Comment: But this still means that someone has to manually copy paste the content into the user controls, right?

Comment: No, my recommendation assumed that you would be able to use .NET user controls on your other site...now knowing it is EpiServer I don't know if that is possible. You could just add a Label control to the user control and then open the HTML in the user control code-behind, read it into a string, and set the Label's Text property to the HTML.

Comment: That's pretty clever man ;-) I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can include iframes in custom masterpage as header and footer and link them to static html pages.
It's maybe not the best idea but it is easiest one.

Answer (score 0):

If yours is a Publishing Site, you can use "Reusable Content" list. the purpose of this list is to store re-usable pieces of html.

You can develop a custom user control which may have a property to refer to an item in that list and then access the list item and render the content at run time. Or there may already be a control out there, please search on internet.

More information:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2011/04/08/reusable-content-in-sharepoint-publishing-html-fields-part-1.aspx